# How to use Facebook Graph APIs instead of FQL?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-4, facebook-fql

Currently, the client sends an `access_token` to the server which is used by FQL to get additional details regarding the user.

Now, since FQL is getting deprecated ([FQL Official](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)), I want to migrate to using the Graph API.

With FQL, I could do the following:

```
Fql.execute("SELECT email, birthday_date, sex, pic_big FROM user WHERE uid = me()", {:access_token => access_token })
```

I can't find any docs regarding how I could do the same with the Graph API. The links I found talked about how I need to redirect the use to `auth/facebook` and create a callback to `auth/facebook/callback`. But, I'm not looking to do that in the backend. I want to create a uniform API for web and mobile users (client sends an access token to the backend). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I guess you looked at the wrong places then:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#reading
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.4

For example

```
/me?fields=id,name,email,birthday,gender,picture
```

Make sure you gathered the right permissions.